# Mercurial: Switch working directory to branch without losing changes?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Let's say that I have a named branch 'B1' which I'm doing feature development on.
I am at a good stopping point before a demo though not done with the feature so I:

```
hg up default
hg merge B1
hg ci -m "merged in feature drop"
hg push
```

Now I continue working for a half an hour or so and go to commit only to realize that I forgot to update back to B1 and that my current working directory is on `default` - uhoh. In theory I should be able to just mark my working directory parent as the tip of B1 - is there an easy way to do this?

I could of course commit, update back to B1, and merge my changes back, but then there's an unstable changeset in default and this happens often enough to me that I would like a real solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Two ways. First, the obvious way:

```
hg diff > foo
hg up -C b1
hg import --no-commit foo
rm foo
```

Second, the magical way:

```
hg up -r 'ancestor(., b1)'  # take working dir back to the fork point
hg up b1                    # take it forward to the branch head
```

This way involves merges. Depending on how much your branches have diverged, this may be painless. Or it may be complicated, and you may make a mess of your changes that you haven't saved anywhere. Which is why even magicians like myself prefer to do it the first way.

Comment: just got `abort: patch failed to apply`, hmm well it only broke on one out of the three files

Answer (score 10):

I would use the shelve extension. I think it’s distributed along with TortoiseHg, you can also use it from the UI:

```
hg shelve --all
hg up B1
hg unshelve
```

Comment: I've had bad experiences with shelve. It's adequate, but somehow, mistakes seem to be pretty easy to make with shelve. MQ is similar, but handles managing the patches better.

Comment: For visual-oriented folks, TortoiseHG provides a UI for this workflow.

Comment: @SteveHorn FYI THG shelve is not the same as the HG shelve extension. IMO the `hg shelve` command is far more powerful and uses built in HG merge logic. The THG feature I think was older and is not as useful.

Answer (score 4):

[Rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) allow you to change parent for any commit for wrongly commited changeset.

If you want just change branch for future commit - MQ (as mentioned) or Shelve

Answer (score 2):

Typically for this sort of dynamic approach, I favor mercurial queues.

In your situation, what I would do would be to create a patch on default with the changes, pop the patch off, switch over to B1, and apply the patch.

It goes something like:

```
hg qnew OOPSPATCH
hg qrefresh 
hg qpop 
hg up B1 
hg qpush

<hack hack>

hg qrefresh 
hg qfinish
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to make a patch? I'm looking for something more lightweight/automated than copying the changed files to a temporary location, switching, and then overwritting those files

Comment: @George: yes, mq maintains patches. It's going to look something like: hg qnew OOPSPATCH; hg qrefresh; hg qpop; hg up B1; hg qpush; <hack hack>; hg qrefresh; hg qfinish.   Look into MQ.

Comment: THanks, I will, I assume MQ stands for managed queues? This guy? http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html

Comment: @George: Managed/Mercurial queues, yea. usually known as mq.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is simple `hg up -m B1`

From `hg up --help`:

```
options:  
  …  
  -m --merge      merge uncommitted changes  
  …
```